# ReactiveCommand return values and View feedback loops

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, reactiveui

I'm familiar with the concepts of MVVM and have used MvvmCross, but am trying out ReactiveUI and trying to wrap my head around some concepts.

I'm writing a tool in WPF (maybe branching to other frameworks) for designers to create and edit data files that are then used by another end-user program. I have a `ViewModel` that represents a `DataModel` document and want to perform validation on the data to inform the designers of any potentially breaking behavior. The underlying classes look like this:

```
public class DataModel
{
    // member data here

    public void Validate(Validator validator)
    {
        // perform specific complex validation here and add errors to validator
    }
}

// aggregator for validation errors
public class Validator
{
    public IList<Error> Errors { get; }
}
```

The `ViewModel` should have a `ReactiveCommand Validate` that the `View` can bind to a button, but once it's done, I want to display a dialog to the user showing the validation errors or that none were found. Is there a direct way to pass `Validator.Errors` back to the `View`, or would I have to create an `IObservable` or `ReactiveList` property for the `View` to subscribe?

**Begin Edit**

Thanks to help in the comments, I can figure out how to save on user confirmation using UserErrors. Still trying to figure out return values for validation. Here's what I have so far in my `ViewModel`:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public DataModel Model { get; }
    public ReactiveCommand<List<Error>> { get; protected set; }

    public ViewModel(DataModel model)
    {
        Model = model;

        Validate = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable<List<Error>>(_ => 
        {
            Validator validator = new Validator();
            Model.Validate(validator);

            // not sure how to turn validator.Errors into the IObservable<List<Error>> that ReactiveUI wants me to return.
        });
    }
}
```

Would it be better to make `Validate` a `ReactiveCommand<Error>` and just call `validator.Errors.ToObservable()`? Can I still iterate through the errors in my View?

**End Edit**

Similarly, I would like to have a save function that first performs validation. If no validation errors are found, it saves the `DataModel` to file. If errors are found, the `View` should inform the user and get confirmation before saving. What's the ReactiveUI way of handling this feedback loop of:

Execute `Save` Command -> validation (possibly call `Validate` command?) -> if errors then request confirmation from `View` -> save on confirmation or do nothing

Comment: You should maybe show more code

Comment: ReactiveUI has a UserError concept that may be useful in this scenario. Eg, you found some validation errors, you can Throw a UserError with the Commands to fix the issues if possible. 

https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/docs/basics/errors.md

Comment: Also the sample found here has a couple user thrown errors. https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples/tree/master/ReactiveUI.Samples.Routing

Comment: @GlennWatson That looks very helpful, thanks! My only question there is how would I handle different dialogs for different types of commands? Is there a convenient way to register a new UserError handler as each command is called (i.e. the Validate UserError handler vs the Save UserError handler), or would it be easier to check each command's `IsExecuting`, assuming only one is ever executing at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments there are some examples here:
https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/docs/basics/errors.md

and:
https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples/tree/master/ReactiveUI.Samples.Routing

In regards to the different dialogs for different error types, one approach is you could base it off the RecoveryCommand. Eg show the different options based on what you provide, when you fire the UserError you can provide the RecoveryCommands and then do the custom logic based on it.

Then in the view model of where you handle the errors you can do something like:

```
        // The show command will return the decision from the user how to proceed with a error.
        // The UserError will have a number of recovery options associated with it, which the dialog 
        // will present to the user. In testing mode this will likely be the test triggering the recovery command.
        // We will wait until one of those recovery commands is executed, then get the result from it.
        ShowCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable(x =>
        {
            var userError = x as UserError;

            // We must always have a valid user error. 
            if (userError == null)
            {
                return Observable.Throw<RecoveryOptionResult>(new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Expected a UserError but got {0}", x)));
            }

            Error = userError;
            Message = Error.ErrorMessage;

            // This fancy statement says go through all the recovery options we are presenting to the user
            // subscribe to their is executing event, if the event fires, get the return result and pass that back
            // as our return value for this command.
            return (Error.RecoveryOptions.Select(cmd => cmd.IsExecuting.SelectMany(_ => !cmd.RecoveryResult.HasValue ? Observable.Empty<RecoveryOptionResult>() : Observable.Return(cmd.RecoveryResult.Value)))).Merge().Take(1);
        });
```

I assume as you said that only one command will be executed. I basically will combine the different recovery commands IsExecuting into one, and when the first one is clicked I assume that is the recovery option I want.

Then where you throw the recovery command you can handle it how you need:

```
        var retryCommand = new RecoveryCommand("Retry") { IsDefault = true };
        retryCommand.Subscribe(_ => retryCommand.RecoveryResult = RecoveryOptionResult.RetryOperation);

        var userError = new UserError(errorMessage, errorResolution, new[] { retryCommand, RecoveryCommand.Cancel });

        switch (await UserError.Throw(userError))
        {
            case RecoveryOptionResult.RetryOperation:
                await Setup();
                break;
            case RecoveryOptionResult.FailOperation:
            case RecoveryOptionResult.CancelOperation:
                if (HostScreen.Router.NavigateBack.CanExecute(null))
                {
                    HostScreen.Router.NavigateBack.Execute(null);
                };

                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
```

Another approach may be to derive off UserError class, and show the different dialogs based on which class type comes up. Eg keep a dictionary of controls that you want to display based on the class type. When you register your handler for displaying the error dialog just show the appropriate dialog.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! I opted to not throw `UserError` for my `Validate` command and just return `Observable.Return(validator.Errors)`, since that dialog is purely informational.

Answer (score -2):

Below example shows the usage of Commands to do validation. I used an inbuilt do-nothing command called NavigationCommands.Search. Button:Click calls DataModel:Validate which if finds errors, populates the passed in Validator.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window ...>    
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="NavigationCommands.Search" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>

    <Grid>
        ...
        <Button Content="Button" Command="NavigationCommands.Search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="229,28,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Mainwindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace WpfCommands
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        DataModel dm = new DataModel();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }

        private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Validator myValidator = new Validator();

            dm.Validate(myValidator);
            if (myValidator.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Errors !");
                // do something with errors
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DataModel.cs

```
namespace WpfCommands
{
    public class DataModel
    {
        public void Validate(Validator v)
        {
            // do some validation
            v.Errors.Add(new Error() { Message = "Error1" });
        }
    }

    // aggregator for validation errors
    public class Validator
    {
        IList<Error> _errors = new List<Error>();

        public IList<Error> Errors { get { return _errors; } }
    }

    public class Error
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the person is asking about a particular MVVM framework called ReactiveUI, not about WPF commands in general.

Comment: Yes, I would like to do this the ReactiveUI way, not the WPF way. Sorry for the confusion.